# PC Freezing due to asus mv2 motherboard

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, freeze

My PC is freezing up (no blue screen just stuck) when I scroll fast through a webpage or sometimes watch you tube. A hard reset is the only way to get it back. It seems to be unrelated to the length of time the PC is on. This has been happening for some time but the PC is not frequently used. Other times it is fine playing games ect.

I believed it was because I have a asus mv2 motherboard with a pci express 1.0 slot and the graphics card as a gforce card 2.0. There was articals referring to how these cards were not backward comparable as they should be.

I am now using a ATI Radon HD 5450 PCI Express 2.1 (latest drivers from ATI on windows vista) that should be backward compatible however the pc still freezes. I cannot seem to purchase a 1.0 card and not sure if this is the issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: Does the computer freeze only when using a browser or also when watching video via WMplayer/games - I agree it sounds like a video card, but just asking.

Comment: Can freeze in any application, tends to be when a large image is loading or a lot is refreshing on the screen (e.g. maximize app at same time as loading webpage)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there isn't adequate information to diagnose the problem, the OP hasn't returned in 4 yrs so no clarification will be forthcoming, and the problem must have long since been overtaken by events so no longer needs to be solved.